# How to send XML data from a laravel app using Httpful library?

Tags: php, xml, api, laravel

I want to use an API which recommends sending data in XML format instead of a POST request. I found a library name HTTPFUL. It sounds quite nice to me and is open to contribute on github.

I tried making an API call from my local server. The code is as follows:

```
public function sms()
{
    $uri = "http://sms.webmates.co.in/api/postsms.php";
    $xml = '<MESSAGE>
<AUTHKEY>10****************272</AUTHKEY>
<SENDER>RSSSSS</SENDER>
<ROUTE>template</ROUTE>
<CAMPAIGN>Sign Up SMS</CAMPAIGN>
<COUNTRY>91</COUNTRY>
<SMS TEXT="test message1">
<ADDRESS TO="9********0"></ADDRESS>
</SMS>
</MESSAGE>';

    $response = \Httpful\Request::post($uri)->body($xml)
        ->sendsXml()
        ->send();
    echo $response->body;
}
```

The echo statement results in `code: 201`. This error doesn't seem from the 
API because no API call is reflected on the API server website. I do not understand what this response means.

Comment: 201 is the http code for "Created". It should mean your request was successful and a message was created, see : https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: @Arend Okay, but the intended action isn't being carried out. I'm trying to send an SMS using an API. On the API side, not request is reflected.

Comment: @vivek : this error comes when XML gets broken, and the server couldn't authenticate.
Error :201 stands for "Invalid username and password" (in this API only), 
and most probable reason for this is , your <SMS TEXT> contains double quotes in message.

Comment: I'm testing with the same code pasted in my question. There are no double quotes in the message. Could you please suggest in any changes in the above code.

Comment: According to this doc here :
http://sms.webmates.co.in/apidoc/textsms/xml-send-sms.php#xmlcontent

The XML is to assigned to a "data" paramter, have a look at the URL below 

http://sms.webmates.co.in/api/postsms.php?data=%3CMESSAGE%3E%0A%3CAUTHKEY%3EYour%20auth%20key%3C/AUTHKEY%3E%0A%3CSENDER%3ESenderID%3C/SENDER%3E%0A%3CROUTE%3ETemplate%3C/ROUTE%3E%0A%3CCAMPAIGN%3Ecampaign%20name%3C/CAMPAIGN%3E%0A%3CCOUNTRY%3Ecountry%20code%3C/COUNTRY%3E%0A%3CSMS%20TEXT%3D%22message1%22%3E%0A%3CADDRESS%20TO%3D%22number1%22%3E%3C/ADDRESS%3E%0A%3C/SMS%3E%0A%3C/MESSAGE%3E%0A